# fancybox with button helper and Thumbnail helper

Tags: button, fancybox, thumbnails, helper

How can I add fancybox with the button helper and thumbnail helper?
And is it possible for the buttons(button helper) to be put under the image so that I can watch and select which I want to see?

the buttons

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
    prevEffect      : 'none',
    nextEffect      : 'none',
    closeBtn        : false,
    helpers     : { 
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    }
});
```

});

and the thumbnail code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers : {
        title   : {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.8,
            css : {
                'background-color' : '#000'
            }
        },
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50
        }
    }
});
```

});

I am a bit new with JavaScript I couldn't get it to work.
What I am trying to do is mix them together and put the buttons on the bottom

P.S. Can I also uses fancybox thumbnail helper to work with Youtube videos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to load the `jquery.fancybox-buttons` and `jquery.fancybox-thumbs` **js** and **css** files apart from the fancybox regular js and css files. They are under the subdirectory "helpers" of the zip file.

Comment: thanks. but What is the fancybox buttons and thumbnails code.(buttons and thumbnails in one code) i would like to have the code and from there on out i think i can handle it. Thank You

Comment: you need both, the external js and css files and the code. I don't see anything wrong with the code so I assumed you are missing to load the files, aren't you?

Comment: okay i tried to edit the external js and css file, to get button helper and thumbnail helper but i can't find what to edit to get it working, i am not sure where the position:bottom; code should go to get the buttons below. i am not to good with javascript :(

Comment: Two separated things: 1. to have either (or both) button and thumbs, you need jquery js file and fancybox js and css files + thumbs js and css files + buttons js and css files. 2. the default position for buttons is on top of the image and thumbs at the bottom. There is not any API option to change that default position of any (buttons or thumbs) and if you don't feel very comfortable with jquery and css then the customization might a be a little bit difficult. You may need somebody else to do it for you (I haven't so far)

Comment: as per v2.1.4, you can select the position for either the thumbs and buttons helpers. The options are `top` or `bottom`. check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs -- find `Options for thumbnail helper` and/or  `Options for button helper`